# How do I pass data from a React app to Alan Studio and receive that data in Alan Studio?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a news reader website where a user can give commands to Alan AI(navigate to a certain page, read news article, etc) and it will execute those commands. I'm storing all the news articles in a Redux state and they need to be passed to Alan Studio so that Allan can read them. How can I pass the articles to Alan Studio? and what script do I need to write in order to receive it in Alan Studio?. So far this is what I have after reading their documentation on how to send data, I have no idea how I can receive this data.

React Code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { setArticles, articlesList } = this.props;

    this.alanBtnInstance = alanBtn({
      key: ALAN_API_KEY,
      onCommand: ({ command, articles }) => {
        if (command === 'newHeadlines') {
          setArticles(articles);
        }
      }
    });

    this.alanBtnInstance.setVisualState({
      data: JSON.stringify(articlesList)
    });
  }
```

Alan Studio Code:

```
intent('Give me the news from $(source* (.*))', p => {
    let NEWS_API_URL = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?apiKey=${NEWS_API_KEY}`;
    
    if(p.source.value) {
        NEWS_API_URL = `${NEWS_API_URL}&sources=${p.source.value.toLowerCase().split(" ").join('-')}`
    }
    
    api.request(NEWS_API_URL, (error, response, body) => {
        const { articles } = JSON.parse(body);
        
        if(!articles.length) {
            p.play('Sorry, please try searching for news from a different source');
            return;
        }
        
        savedArticles = articles;
        
        p.play({ command: 'newHeadlines', articles });
        p.play(`Here are the (latest|recent) news from ${p.source.value}.`);
        
        p.play('Would you like me to read the headlines?');
        p.then(confirmation)
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*thats the code that you have to write in alan script*/

projectAPI.greetUser = function(p, param, callback) {
     if (param) {
         p.play(`Nice to see you again, ${param.user}`);
     } else {
         p.play('Welcome to our app');
     }
     callback();
 };

/*thats your function on client side to send objects*/


function sendData() {
    alanBtnInstance.activate();
    alanBtnInstance.callProjectApi("greetUser", {
      user: 'John Smith'
    }, function(error, result) {});
  };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).